# /private folder on OSX lost it's '@' attribute

Tags: macos, finder

Somehow my /private folder lost it's '@' attribute. Now, the folder shows up in my finder:

```
0 drwxr-xr-x    6 root  wheel       204 Mar  1 21:25 private
```

This is what it should be:

```
0 drwxr-xr-x@   6 root  wheel       204 Mar  1 21:25 private
```

How do I set it back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an indicator of extended attributes. On my machine, it's only `com.apple.FinderInfo`, with the value:

```
$ xattr -p com.apple.FinderInfo private
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

The first eight bytes are type and creator codes, the next four are [Finder flags](http://developer.apple.com/legacy/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/Finder_Interface/finder_interface.pdf) (page 13).

On my machine, only `kIsInvisible` is set, so it's possible that when you navigate to your disk root folder, `private` is visible.

Enter the following in Terminal to restore its hidden state and the associated extended attribute:

```
sudo chflags hidden /private
```

Comment: Thnx. Worked like a charm